# confused about scope and heap memory lifetime

Tags: c++

okay so I'm trying to grasp the concept of the heap and its scope

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){

    {
        int* x = new int(10);
    }

    std::cout<<*x;//ERROR Use of undeclared identifier 'x'
}
```

but since I allocated it to the heap, why doesn't it exist anymore after the scope of the block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but since I allocated it to the heap, why doesn't it exist anymore after the scope of the block?

`x` is an automatic variable, and thus it does not exist outside of the scope where it was declared.

The object that you allocated dynamically **does** still exist. But since after the life time of `x` there is no longer any pointer pointing to that object, it is no longer possible to use it nor to delete it. This is called a memory leak.

Answer (score 3):

The allocated block of memory is independent from the variable containing its address. The memory still exists, but the variable doesn't, because its scope ends at the curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

The dynamically-alocated integer still exists (on the heap). Only the pointer to it (`x`) is out of scope.

Try this:

```
int main() {
    int* x;
    {
        x = new int(10);
    }

    std::cout << *x;
}
```

---

Also, don't forget to free the memory when you're done using it:

```
delete x;
```

Comment: That would work even without any dynamic allocation, so I'm not convinced that it's a good example.

Comment: @Fureeish no, it wouldn't work without dynamic allocation. `int* x; { int y = 10; x = &y; } std::cout << *x;` would have UB.

Comment: @eerorika that's not what I had in mind. In the very code in the answer, if you remove the asteriks and `new`, it would do exactly the same. The code you provided is way better and imo should be used as a counterexample.

Comment: @Fureeish I don't see how removing dynamic allocation would demonstrate that a dynamically allocated object exists outside of the scope where it was allocated.

Comment: I did not suggest that it should. The example should demonstrate the difference and here we observe no difference between dynamic or automatic lifetime. I would ask this - how that very example shows that the dynamically allocated object still exists? In what way does it demonstrate anything? My analogy was that if we change the dynamic allocation to automatic allocation, we would observe no difference. Your code in the first comment is not doing the same, thus I consider it a better example